# Protractor : Angular e2e testing repeat selector

Tags: protractor

[image]

Need to select Shweta and click on that, how can I achieve that using repeat locator in protractor? I've tried some possible solutions, but it's not working. Could anybody please tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: why you don't copy your code/html instead of putting image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using element.all() with by.repeater() combination as shown below and index could be either 0,1,2,.. its depends on the number of elements you could get with ng-repeat='project in projects' locator.

**Code**

```
    element.all(by.repeater('project in projects'))
                .get(index)
                .element(by.css("h2"))
                .click();
```

Comment: Hi i tried the above code , i am getting this error :  element.all(..).row is not a function.

Comment: @  Suresh Salloju , i tried the updated code , its working ....thank u...

Answer (score 0):

You can locate all the elements in a repeater using the [`by.repeater()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) locator and [filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the one having the "Shweta" title:

```
var repeater = element.all(by.repeater('project in projects'));
var project = repeater.filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.$(".panel-body a h2").getText().then(function (title) {
        return title.trim() === "Shweta";
    });
}); 
project.$(".panel-body a").click();
```